# Looper: missing argument error

Tags: scrnaseq, yaml, looper

While trying to run [looper](https://github.com/pepkit/looper) I am getting the following error:

> Error (missing attribute): 'sandro_rna_seq' requires sample attribute '/scratch/nv4e/sandro_looper/pipeline/jyvo_experiment-metadata.yaml' for option/argument '-E'
>   Not submitted: Required attribute(s) missing for pipeline arguments string

In my `pipeline_interface.yaml` file I have the following:

```
arguments:
  "-L": "IU"
  "-T": "gencode_mouse_m13"
  "-E": "/scratch/nv4e/sandro_looper/pipeline/jyvo_experiment-
metadata.yaml"
```

The file `"/scratch/nv4e/sandro_looper/pipeline/jyvo_experiment-metadata.yaml"` is definitely present but it still gives an error...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the argument values incorrectly. Argument values are sample attributes, not full character paths. Hence, "IU" is a sample attribute, "gencode_mouse_m13" is a sample attribute, so why would you think "/scratch..." would be treated any differently?

The pipeline interface maps sample attributes to command-line arguments. It is modulated by sample (different values per sample). What you're trying to do is pass a constant string to an argument.

For this, there is a `pipeline_args` section of your project config. Please read the docs on [project config](https://pepkit.github.io/docs/project_config/).